# Find allowed error of an argument regarding the allowed error of a function.

Tags: approximation, computational-mathematics

To what precision can $x$ be obtained with logarithmic table (with $5$ digit table) if $x$ lies between $300$ and $400$?

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you compute the error in the function given the error in the argument? Then turn the argument around.

Comment: Depends on the spacing and range in the table and which logs are tabulated (I guess base 10?) Further: What kind of interpolation is allowed? E.g. Abramowitz and Stegun list the errors for linear interpolation and the degree for which full table precision is achieved. Thus if you have a table range from 1 to 10 you can get max 6 digits.

Comment: @gammatester thanks. What I need is the solution, not the answer. $x$ lies between 300 and 400